# Discrepancy in Google analytics data vs CRM transaction data

Tags: google-analytics

My transactions in Google analytics were more than real transaction data. When I stopped an A/B test that was running the problem as solved. The traffic from the internal data (i.e A/B) test was filtered. Does anyone have an idea why that A/B test caused the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of possibilites here

1. GA integration for your a/b test service is not enabled
2. Variation/Experiment pages might not be sending data to GA
3. GA transaction are double counted on page reload

   For the first two you would have to check your integrations then test on both original and variation pages to see if data was passed to GA

   For reload issue, you would have to to redirect users to home or cart page when the thank you page is refreshed after transaction.

Hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think the third option is more likely, because the other ones decrease the number of transaction while our issue is the increase in the number of transactions.  Do you have any experience with VWO (an A/B test tool) ?  we used in our GA 360 and caused this discrepancy problem.